# Getting error code 201 CCAvenue payment gateway

Tags: magento2, ccavenue, magento-fpc

I am suddenly getting a 201 error code on my CCAvenue payment gateway. I'm not able to find any information on CCAvenue's site for this error code 201.

Why this is happening? What is the meaning of error code 201?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was FPC, CCavenue doesn't working with Full page cache in magento 2.

Answer (score 3):

You need to send unique dynamic tid value every time.

```
<input type="hidden" value="153233" readonly="" id="tid" name="tid">
```

Check TID field value it must be random and unique.